# React: Update state for a particular element

Tags: reactjs

I am creating an program where a user should type a correct version of a shuffled sentence. Like on the picture below.

[image]

What I want is when a user has a correct answer, a tick is displayed next to an input. For example.

[image]

However, not for all inputs but for one that is correct. To implement this functionality I use state, but it does not give me a desired result. How can I make sure that a tick is displayed next to a particular line?

My code is the following.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bulma-components/full";
import { MdDoneAll } from "react-icons/md";
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");


export default class DialogueShuffleFrame2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shuffledArray: [],
      inputAnswer: "",
      score:0,
      showTick:false
    };
    this.writeSomething = this.writeSomething.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const shuffle = a => {
      var j, x, i;
      for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
      }
      return a;
    };

    let shuffledArray =
      this.props.lines[0].parts &&
      this.props.lines[0].parts.map(obj => {
        return {
          id: uuidv1(),
          parts: {
            speaker: obj.speaker,
            words: shuffle(obj.words.split(" "))
          },
          correctAnswer: obj.words
        };
      });

    this.setState({
      shuffledArray
    });
  }

  writeSomething(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      inputAnswer: e.target.value
    });
  }

  checkLines(str, obj) {
    obj.map(item => {
        //console.log(item.correctAnswer)
        if (item.correctAnswer === str.trim()) {

            //console.log('correct')
            this.setState({
                score:this.state.score + 80,
                inputAnswer:'',
                showTick:true
            })
        }
        return true
    })
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state.shuffledArray);
    const shuffles =
      this.state.shuffledArray &&
      this.state.shuffledArray.map(item => (

        <li key={item.id}>
          <input onChange={this.writeSomething} />
          {this.state.showTick && <MdDoneAll style={{color:'blue'}}/>}
          <Button
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                this.checkLines(this.state.inputAnswer, this.state.shuffledArray);
              }}
              size="small"
            >
              Check
            </Button>
          {item.parts.words.map((word, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{`${word} `}</span>
          ))}
        </li>
      ));
    return (
      <div>
        Dialogue 3<ul>{shuffles}</ul>
        {this.state.score}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should add a showTick property for each element of shuffledArray. use this to show or hide the tick mark

Comment: wow great idea!

Comment: you need to have component for each question which hold state for show tick!

Answer (score 2):

`this.state.showTick` is universal in your case. Once set true, it is used for every element. 
You need to change that to an object and use the `item.id` to show the tick.

First:

```
 this.state = {
      shuffledArray: [],
      inputAnswer: "",
      score:0,
      showTick:{}
    };
```

```
checkLines(itemId, str, obj) {
    obj.map(item => {
        //console.log(item.correctAnswer)
        if (item.correctAnswer === str.trim()) {

            //console.log('correct')
            this.setState({
                score:this.state.score + 80,
                inputAnswer:'',
                showTick:{...this.state.showTick, itemId : true}
            })
        }
        return true
    })
  }
```

```
<li key={item.id}>
          <input onChange={this.writeSomething} />
          {this.state.showTick[item.id] && <MdDoneAll style={{color:'blue'}}/>}
          <Button
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                this.checkLines(item.id, this.state.inputAnswer, this.state.shuffledArray);
              }}
              size="small"
            >
              Check
            </Button>
          {item.parts.words.map((word, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{`${word} `}</span>
          ))}
        </li>
```

Let me know if it works. It's hard to test it without the whole code.

Comment: Thanks, for sure!

Comment: Hi @paruchuri-p thank you for leading me to a correct answer. Although, I have get it done without using state, however I do not know whose implementation is better yours or mine. Since I have not checked yours.

Comment: By the way, unfortunately,  I could not get it right with your code, so let me post my code as a correct one.

Comment: Oh. What was the issue? Your code looks fine. But it's better if you have the component controlled. You are mutating the object for this and while it works in this case, it doesn't work in most cases.

Comment: I could not really figure it out, I think there may be an issue with id

Comment: I can share my github and you can try to fix it on your local machine

Comment: Yeah, I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have added a property showTick in my generated object in componentDidMount, showTick:false

```
    const shuffle = a => {
      var j, x, i;
      for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
      }
      return a;
    };

    let shuffledArray =
      this.props.lines[0].parts &&
      this.props.lines[0].parts.map(obj => {
        return {
          id: uuidv1(),
          parts: {
            speaker: obj.speaker,
            words: shuffle(obj.words.split(" ")),
            showTick:false
          },
          correctAnswer: obj.words
        };
      });

    this.setState({
      shuffledArray
    });
  }
```

Then in `checkLines` function I assigned `showTick` to `true`

```
checkLines(str, obj) {
    obj.map(item => {
        //console.log(item.correctAnswer)
        if (item.correctAnswer === str.trim()) {

            //console.log('correct')
            this.setState({
                score:this.state.score + 80,
                inputAnswer:''
            })
            item.parts.showTick = true
        }
        return true
    })
  }
```

Then in render part I showed it.

```
render() {
    //console.log(this.state.shuffledArray);
    const shuffles =
      this.state.shuffledArray &&
      this.state.shuffledArray.map(item => (

        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.parts.speaker}
          <input onChange={this.writeSomething} />
          {item.parts.showTick && <MdDoneAll style={{color:'blue'}}/>}
          <Button
              color="primary"
              onClick={() => {
                this.checkLines(this.state.inputAnswer, this.state.shuffledArray);
              }}
              size="small"
            >
              Check
            </Button>
          {item.parts.words.map((word, index) => (
            <span key={index}>{`${word} `}</span>
          ))}
        </li>
      ));
    return (
      <div>
        Dialogue 3<ul>{shuffles}</ul>
        {this.state.score}
      </div>
    );
  }
```